# Calling a function in a fragment of a view pager from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, kotlin

I have a activity which contains few checkboxs and a view pager which slides in every 30 sec. I want to change the image when i check the checkbox in the parent activity. But while calling function "flipImage()" in the fragment gets the image view as null and also when i click the image the onClickListener is not working.

```
class SomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var viewPagerAdapter : SectionsPagerAdapter by Delegates.notNull<SectionsPagerAdapter>()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_slides)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        viewPagerAdapter = SectionsPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)

        vp_image_slides.adapter = viewPagerAdapter

        btnImageFlip.setOnCheckedChangeListener({
            checkbox, b ->

            val slideImageFrag = viewPagerAdapter.getItem(vp_image_slides.currentItem) as SlideImageFragment
            slideImageFrag.flipImage()
        })
    }


    inner class SectionsPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {


            return SlideImageFragment.newInstance(someUri)
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {

            return 4
        }


    }

}
```

and In My Fragment

```
    class SlideImageFragment : Fragment() {

        var uri: Uri? = null
        val TAG = SlideImageFragment.javaClass.simpleName



        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            if (arguments != null) {
                uri = arguments.getParcelable(IMAGE_URI)

            }
        }


        override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
            if (uri != null) {


                Glide.with(view).load(uri).into(iv_slide_image)

//Not working
                iv_slide_image.setOnClickListener {

                    val activity = activity as ImageSlidesActivity
                    activity.toggle()
                    Log.e(TAG, "Image is clicke2d")
                }

            }

        }



        fun flipImage() {


        //here I am getting iv_slide_image as null
            if (iv_slide_image != null)
                iv_slide_image.rotationX = 180f
        }


        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                                  savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

            Log.e(TAG, "onCreateView")
            val view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_slide_image, container, false)


            return view

        }




        companion object {

            val IMAGE_URI = "image"
            fun newInstance(uri: Uri): SlideImageFragment {
                val fragment = SlideImageFragment()
                val args = Bundle()
                args.putParcelable(IMAGE_URI, uri)
                fragment.arguments = args
                return fragment
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How did you define the variable iv_slide_image ? is it through kotlin-android-extensions ?

Comment: yes..I used kotlin-android-extension @tskulbru

Comment: try with pager adapter instead of fragmentpagerAdapter  http://www.androhub.com/android-image-slider-using-viewpager/

Comment: FragmentViewPager is extended by the PagerAdapter class.. Don't know how is this going to solve my problem.. @pravin